# How can I check if a directory is on the path in Bash?

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash: Detect if user's path has a specific directory in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396066/bash-detect-if-users-path-has-a-specific-directory-in-it)

Given a directory, how can I determine whether it's on the unix PATH? Looking for a shell script.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Why is the directory more important than the executable?

Comment: If the shell script you're looking for is executable you may want to use `which` to simplify.

Comment: I do want to vote to close this, but I searched Google and the site for my terminology and couldn't find anything, so maybe it's good to also have this. Up to you

Comment: @KevinBurke: Closed questions can still be found via Google, as long as they're not deleted.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can write:

```
if [[ :$PATH: == *:"$directory_you_want_to_check":* ]] ; then
    # O.K., the directory is on the path
else
    # oops, the directory is not on the path
fi
```

Note that this won't follow symbolic links, or anything like that; it's just a string comparison, checking if colon-$PATH-colon contains colon-directory-colon.

Answer (score 6):

I usually prefer `case` -- posting this in order to make the set complete (-:

```
case :$PATH: in
  *:/home/you/bin:*)  ;;  # do nothing
  *) PATH=/home/you/bin:$PATH ;;
esac
```

Notice the leading and trailing colons on the case expression in order to simplify the pattern. With `case $PATH` you would have to compare to four different patterns, depending on whether the beginning and end of the match was at the beginning or end of the variable.

Comment: Elegant, very nice indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty: you can echo the (slightly modified) path through `grep` and check the return value:

```
pax> echo ":$PATH:" | grep :/usr/sbin:
:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:

pax> echo $?
0

pax> echo ":$PATH:" | grep :/usr/xbin:

pax> echo $?
1
```

By putting `:` at either end of both the path and the directory you're looking for, you simply the `grep` expression and ensure only complete paths are found. Otherwise, looking for `/usr/bin` may turn up `/usr/bin/xyzzy` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I will probably have something like that, that is to echo the existing $PATH and grep for the pattern.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
 echo "$0 <dir>"
 exit 1
fi 

dir=${1%/};

if [ `echo :$PATH: | grep -F :$dir:` ]; then
   echo "$dir is in the UNIX path"
else
   echo "$dir is not in the UNIX path"
fi
```

Comment: This fails if the directory is first or last on the path.  This is simple to fix, of course, but then, see the other answers.

Comment: Thanks mate for the error detection and updated the answer. Appreciated your input.

Comment: Not exactly the correct fix, though.  You want `echo :$PATH:` to make sure the path is correctly delimited.  You might want to use `fgrep` to avoid accidental regex characters matching the wrong thing, too.

Comment: Does it need more changes or is this ok to you? (-;

Comment: Welp, you could copy/paste my answer but then I'd have to kill you. (-:

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it can helps:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/usr/xbin"
[ `echo ":$PATH:" | grep :$DIR:` ] && echo true || echo false
```